# How do I set the names of a list on each iteration through a loop

Tags: r

```
my_list <- list()
for(i in 1:2) {my_list[[i]] <- i^2}
> str(my_list)
List of 2
 $ : num 1
 $ : num 4
```

If I wanted the key of each iteration to be e.g. "iteration1", "iteration2" etc, how would I build that as I go on each iteration in the loop?

Right now there is no key? I think: `names(my_list)` returns NULL. How can I make it so that the names, or keys, are "iteration1", "iteration2" etc?

Comment: Just do `my_list <- setNames(as.list((1:2)^2), paste0("iteration", 1:2))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean something like this:

```
my_list <- list()
for(i in 1:2) {my_list[[paste0("iteration", i)]] <- i^2}
names(my_list)
[1] "iteration1" "iteration2"
```

Or use naming **outside** of the loop:

```
my_list <- list()
for(i in 1:2) {my_list[[i]] <- i^2}
names(my_list) <- paste0("iteration", 1:2)
```